# Inout argument in nested function in Swift

Tags: swift

I was practicing Swift and I was trying to implement my own map function. Well, not the same as in Haskell, because I wanted it to modify passed list (experiments with inout parameters). Is it possible? Because I wrote this code:

```
func my_map<T>(f: T -> T) -> ([T] -> Void) {
    func go(inout l : [T]) -> Void {
        for i in 0..<l.count {
            l[i] = f(l[i])
        }
    }
    return go
}

var li = [1,5,3]
my_map({ $0 * 3 })(&li)
println(li)
```

And it gets following errors (and I completely don't know why):

> error: '[T]' is not a subtype of 'inout [T]'
>
> return go
>
> ^
>
> error: unexpected trailing closure
>
> my_map2({ $0 * 3 })(&li)
>
> ^

I'm using http://swiftstub.com

Is it possible to do what I want to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible. The error message from Xcode 7 is more helpful:

```
error: cannot convert return expression of type '(inout [T]) -> Void' to return type '([T]) -> Void'
    return go
           ^~
```

Which means that you only have to add `inout` to the
parameter declaration of the return type of `my_map`:

```
func my_map<T>(f: T -> T) -> ((inout [T]) -> Void) {
//                             ^^^^^
    func go(inout l : [T]) -> Void {
        for i in 0..<l.count {
            l[i] = f(l[i])
        }
    }
    return go
}

var li = [1,5,3]
my_map({ $0 * 3 })(&li)
print(li)
// [3, 15, 9]
```

You can write it slightly more compact as:

```
func my_map<T>(f: T -> T) -> ((inout [T]) -> Void) {
    return { (inout l : [T]) in
        l = l.map(f)
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much! I should have inferred it from error description, but somehow it wasn't that intuitive.